# Better Practice: Printing from void method OR returning value from method and printing from method caller

Tags: java

Which would be considered the better practice(if any) between printing a value from a void method with parameters or returning a value to the method caller and printing it in the method caller? For instance, the first code excerpt is the former and the second code excerpt is the latter:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    printValue(5);
}

public static void printValue(int number){
    if(number == 10)
        System.out.println("Message A");

    else
        System.out.println("Message B");
}
```

and

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println(getValue(5));
}

public static String getValue(int number){
    if(number == 10)
        return "Message A";

    else
        return "Message B";
}
```

Comment: generally there is no difference. just make sure your method is consistent. If you use method 1, then use it in your whole project

Comment: Think about this, functions or methods shouldn't have side effects.  In this case, `printValue` is (reasonably) clear in it's intentions and `getValue` does the same.  If `getValue` also printed the value, then that would be of concern. Sure, you can use debug statements in your code where you like, but you should be able to turn these off and the code should operate the same way...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of things I would change:
 1. write according to Java code conventions (regarding [using brackets](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-142311.html#449))
 2. have only one exit point from the method:

```
public static String getValue(int number){
    String result = null;
    if(number == 10) {
        result = "Message A";
    } else {
        result = "Message B";
    }
    return result;
}
```

And last, it doesn't matter where you print it - but I would prefer printing inside the method - this way if you have more than one caller - you don't have to re-implement printing the result in different places.

Comment: Why does java allow not using brackets when I only have one statement? I read the link and it stated that I should avoid it, I acknowledge that. One last thing, what's the reason for having only one exit point? Forgive all the questions, I must ask in order to fully comprehend. Makes sense to print it in the method if I'm making several calls, I understand that.

Comment: @KermittheHermit One-entry and one-exit point is a concept to make your code more easily understood.  Sure, when the method is only a view lines long, it's probably easy to spot the embedded `return` statements, but when the start to increase in length and complexity, `return` statements disappear really quickly and can make it more difficult for people to understand what the code is doing. It's also the same concept that you should avoid using `return` statements as control blocks and use `break` and `if` statements better.

Comment: @KermittheHermit Java does allow you leave out braces (`{...}`) if you only have a single line of code `if (something) somethingelse;`, but it's really easy to add logic to that statement which you "think" should be included, but won't be because you forget to add the braces in. General practice suggests always adding the braces as it, again, makes the intention much clearer and the code easier to reader...

Comment: @MadProgrammer That makes sense, I can imagine debugging many lines of code looking for return statements would be tedious and error-prone. As for the braces, if you put it like that, it seems like a safe practice and can avoid confusion by always using braces then. Thank you for the insight, I appreciate it.

Comment: @KermittheHermit You only need to have spent hours (and sometimes days) tracking issues related to these things to appreciate why it should be done this way ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer If you put it like that, I look forward to being so unfortunate ;)

Answer (score 0):

The advantage of the first approach is that you have encapsulated the output method so that even if you call `printValue` from many places you can change a single location if you need to add conditional behavior or print the value in a different manner.

The advantage of the second approach is that you can write tests to validate your value conversion.

You might even want to combine the approaches if you need both advantages by having `printValue()` call `getValue()` so that you can write tests against `getValue()` as well as encapsulate the output mechanism in `printValue()`.

If your requirements do not dictate a most useful approach I recommend that you prioritize clarity of the code and figure you will refactor your code when your requirements change.

Answer (score 0):

The second approach is going to be better in most practical applications.

1. It is easily testable through automation instead of manually checking the console
2. It allows you to use the value for more than just printing.

The activity being performed is to pick the correct message string.  If we rename the method to something more descriptive we might select

```
public static String determineMessageFromValue(int number)
```

alternatively if you kept the print inside of the method

```
public static String determineAndPrintMessageFromValue(int number)
```

which is wordier and probably more specific than you want it to be.

It may seem a little bit like overkill if the goal of the program is always to do something to the console but it helps you think in responsibilities when you using this code in a more complex system.  For instance, having a method printing to console wouldn't be as that useful if you decided to display the value on a java swing UI & also on a web page.